# Compilation issue with sitmo prng, c++11, and armadillo

Tags: r, c++11, random, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying to compile the [sitmo prng](http://www.sitmo.com/article/parallel-random-number-generator-in-c/) under C++11 within an R package. **[The problematic code has been packaged and is available here.](https://github.com/coatless/sitmo)** The objective of this R package is to make available the [sitmo header file](http://www.sitmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/prng_engine.hpp) so that other packages are able to use the **LinkTo** field within description. As an added bonus, the package is scheduled to ship with an [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) + OpenMP example. There is one other package, [mvnfast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvnfast/index.html), that uses sitmo, but only under c++98 and boost headers.

I believe that the error which I am receiving is specific to `OS X` and `clang`. I haven't been able to replicate it on Windows via [win-build](http://win-builder.r-project.org/). With that being said, the error is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/random:3641:44: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
        const size_t __logR = __log2<uint64_t, _URNG::max() - _URNG::min() + uint64_t(1)>::value;
```

The error has only popped up on the [Rcpp dev list](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2014-June/007705.html). The resolution in this case was to compile under C++98 and use boost.

The above error is followed by the following notes:

```
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/random:3773:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::generate_canonical<double, 53, sitmo::prng_engine>' requested here
        * _VSTD::generate_canonical<_RealType, numeric_limits<_RealType>::digits>(__g)
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/random:3737:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::uniform_real_distribution<double>::operator()<sitmo::prng_engine>' requested here
        {return (*this)(__g, __p_);}
                ^
sitmo_test.cpp:77:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::uniform_real_distribution<double>::operator()<sitmo::prng_engine>' requested here
      double u = distunif(engine);
                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/random:3641:44: note: non-constexpr function 'max' cannot be used in a constant expression
    const size_t __logR = __log2<uint64_t, _URNG::max() - _URNG::min() + uint64_t(1)>::value;
                                           ^
../inst/include/prng_engine.hpp:100:23: note: declared here
  static result_type (max)() { return 0xFFFFFFFF; }
```

The version of **clang** being used is:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Howdy. I will try to take a look, but prolly not tonight. I had sitmo on the list of things to look at too...   Can you maybe bring it to rcpp-devel too?

Comment: Sure, I'll post the question to rcpp-devel as well.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I suspect sitmo is wrong here, please take a look at the answer

Comment: That looks very promising, maybe @Coatless can test is quickly...

Comment: Will do. Walking home at the moment

Comment: All is well in the land of Rcpp once more. It works. I'm adding more docs and I'll push to CRAN tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the code, there is a bug in the sitmo prng_engine.h. `min()` and `max()` were declared as

```
static result_type (min)() { return 0; }

static result_type (max)() { return 0xFFFFFFFF; }
```

If you take a look at, say, standard LCG `max` from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine/max), you could see that it is declared `constexpr`, ditto for `min`.

As soon as you make those methods `constexpr` in the sitmo header file, I believe you could use them in template expression.

UPDATE

I've looked into GCC 5 headers, methods indeed are declared `constexpr`

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you for catching this.

Comment: @Coatless you're welcome. Do you plan to submit report to sitmo guys?